# Php is not receiving data from httpurlconnection

Tags: php, android-studio-2.3

I am sending data from my Android app to php but php is not getting any data. I have doubt that I am missing something in my php code. To connect php and Android, is only php URL is needed in android code or something else I have to do? I have stunk into this problem. Any help would be appreciated.
My full php code is:

```
 <?php
         $user_email=$_POST['email'];
         echo "Email is $user_email";
   ?>
```

My Android code is:

```
URL server_url = new URL("http://www.myURL.com/Jobs/login.php");

      HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) server_url.openConnection();
        //header stuff
        urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        //params
        String urlParameters = "email="+mEmail;
        //send post
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
         DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
         wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();   

        //read result
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString()
       );
```

Comment: If `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` shows "emtpy" (array(0)), then, is not PHP issue, is your Android code.

Comment: I have added my android code please tell me if there is any issue in android

Comment: Is your "mEmail", being actually setted?, I know is a late answer and sorry, as you answer a lot of days after, I didn't follow your question. Check with "email=hello@mail.com" forcing the mEmail to be sended in the params, also, don't set the Content-Language forcing the headers in that way since "hello@mail.com" is not english actually, and as I'm supposing, you have AsyncTask and also try{ } catch(){} and that doesn't show any error?.

Comment: @ Asfo i have tried your solutions ...but nothing works  i have put try and catch but there is no error...also i can receive respond from php but really can not understand why php is not getting the data...i am stunckd here from so many days...please help

Comment: Then I think your CORS Is blocking it without any error, since the POST Method requires your server to be able to receive from anywhere you need to modify it so you can enable the POST out of your own site. Check about "CORS" configurations and include it to your code so PHP is now able to receive from anywhere.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i enable CORS configuration or you can suggest me any related link?

Comment: If you Google "CORS PHP" you find a lot of resources like this one: https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP code doesn't have issue for Optimized code with email filter, if email address there.

Kindly replace your old code.

```
<?php
//Replace your Code by Ajmal Praveen
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$user_email=$_POST['email'];
//sanitizing email by Ajmal Praveen
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo 'Enter a valid email address';
    }
else
{
    //If email is proper show it
    echo 'Email is '.$user_email.'';
}
}
?>
```

You need to check your Android code to see if the field email is properly configured or not.
I'm 100% sure there is no issue with the PHP Code.

Comment: i tried your code and still it is showing that email is not set . I have added my android code please check and reply

Comment: Why you Have down voted my Code? There is issue with your Android code im Sure about that, but i can't help you in Android code because im not Familiar with Android dev.

Comment: I have not voted you down.I tried your code but still my problem is not solved

Comment: @meenakshiagrawal oh Okay.  for PHP Code you can use my code. but the issue is with your Android Code Check the lines Connection, Post method.

Comment: for idea/tutorial i think this post will work for you http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/